# Remove backslashes while sending email in php

Tags: php, email

I am trying to send Email using following code

```
$mess00 = "Store Email: " . $storeEmail . "\r\n"; 
...         
$message = $mess00 . "<br \><br \>" . $mes1 . "<br \><br \>" . $mess0 . "<br \>" . $mess1 . "<br \>" . $mess2 . "<br \>" .  $mess3;

$message = "<html><body><p>".$message."</p></body></html>";
try {
$this->Mail($storeEmail, $subject, $message);
```

Now suppose that If a store name is `StackOver's Inc`. , In email I get `StackOver\'s Inc.` How can I make it so that these \ can be removed when you receive an email.

P.S These names are stored in Database.

Comment: Won't fix your code but you should change all `<br \>` to `<br />`

Comment: environment is linux box ? not sure just verify, is there any magic quotes are enable in PHP.INI ? Or Are you using mysql_real_escape_string any where?

Comment: @Bharanikumar More importantly `mysqli_real_escape_string` (`i`) - `mysql_` is in deprecation.

Comment: @Fred-ii-just verify / confirmation / just ideas

Comment: @Bharanikumar Indeed and a good point.

Comment: `@OP` - If you're going to use `mysqli_real_escape_string` then you'll need to use something to the affect of `$variable = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['varname']);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [stripslashes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) to remove the backslashes before sending the message.

```
$clean_message = stripslashes ($message);
$this->Mail($storeEmail, $subject, $clean_message);
```

Comment: Perfect and succint. Don't know why this isn't the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

This means that the data in your database is already wrong. At the time of insertion you had [`magic_quotes_gpc`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc) enabled; this feature was deprecated in 5.3 and altogether removed in 5.4, but older versions would still have it enabled by default.

Read [this article](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php) about how disable magic quotes in your existing environment if you can't upgrade your installation.

After fixing the above you still have to fix all the affected database entries; you can do this by loading each record, apply [`stripslashes()`](http://php.net/stripslashes) and saving them again.